# Combinatorial Proof of a Binomial Identity $\sum_k {m\choose k} {n \choose k} = {m+n \choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> $$\sum_k {m\choose k} {n \choose k} = {m+n \choose n}$$

In this identity we seem to be choosing subsets that do $\it not$ contain k of type m and type n for all possible k.  In the style of Vandermonde's identity we are then choosing n elements of both types to not be in the set. Where might I go from here to form a full proof?

Comment: A special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337923/summations-with-binomial-coefficients-sum-k-0n-binomrk-binommn-k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that rewriting the identity as
$$
\sum_{k} \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{n-k} = \binom{m+n}{n}
$$
it should be clear.

You are choosing $n$ elements in a set that is the disjoint union of a set $A$ of $m$ elements and a set $B$ of $n$ elements. So for each $k$ you choose $k$ elements from $A$, and the rest from $B$.

Comment: Yes, it is quite obvious now thanks, I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @Stopwatch, you're welcome. I believe very few people can fairly say they never miss the obvious.