# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} \binom{s}{n+k} = \binom{r+s}{r+n}$.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I can't resolve this exercise and I need some tips.

Let be $n$ a integer, $s$ a real number and $r \geq 0$ a integer. Show that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} \binom{s}{n+k} = \binom{r+s}{r+n} $$

Comment: This is also known as Chu-Vandermonde's identity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: Isn't that the case where the second binomial coeff is $s\choose {n-k}$ rather than $s\choose {n+k}$? Perhaps it can be transformed using the hint by Quang Hong given below.

Comment: See also: [How to prove Vandermonde's Identity: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{R}{k}\binom{M}{n-k}=\binom{R+M}{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337923) (And other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/337923).)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^r {r\choose k} {s\choose n+k}.$$

Start from
$${s\choose n+k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+k+1}} (1+z)^s \; dz.$$

This gives the following integral for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\sum_{k=0}^r {r\choose k}
\frac{1}{z^{n+k+1}} (1+z)^s \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^s}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^r {r\choose k}
\frac{1}{z^k}  \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^s}{z^{n+1}}
\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^r \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^s}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{(1+z)^r}{z^r} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{r+s}}{z^{r+n+1}} \; dz.$$

This last integral can be evaluated by inspection and is given by
$$[z^{r+n}] (1+z)^{r+s} = {r+s\choose r+n}.$$
This obviously confirms the combinatorial proof, which is simple.

A trace as to when this method appeared on MSE and by whom starts at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/).

Comment: How do you prove $ \binom{s}{n+k} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+k+1}} (1+z)^s dz $?

Answer (score 1):

Both sides are polynomials in $s$ (the terms of the series are zero when $k>r$), so it suffices to show they are equal when $s$ is a nonnegative integer.

Suppose that I have $s$ statesmen and $r$ robots.  ${{s+r}\choose{n+r}}$ counts the number of ways that we can form a caucus with $n+r$ members.

But if our caucus has $n+k$ statesmen ($0\leq k \leq r$), then we must exclude exactly $k$ robots.  So the number of such caucuses is ${r\choose k}{s \choose {n+k}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\binom{r}{k}=\binom{r}{r-k}$. How many ways can you choose $r+n$ persons out of $r$ men and $s$ women?

Comment: (How do you handle the case where s is not an integer?)

Comment: Ah, I missed that piece of information. One can always return to the binomial theorem version of the proof.