# How to prove that $\sum_{j=0}^k {n\choose j} \cdot{m\choose k -j} = {n+m\choose k}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

I am a high school student and I need help proving that $$\sum_{j=0}^k {n\choose j}  \cdot{m\choose k -j} = {n+m\choose k}.$$

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Hint:  Suppose there are $n$ blue objects and $m$ red ones.  How many ways can I choose $k$ objects if I don't care about the colors?  Count that in two different ways.

Comment: This is a well known problem, it is known as Vandermonde's identity. You can find this problem on this site.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337923/how-to-prove-vandermondes-identity-sum-k-0n-binomrk-binommn-k

Comment: At least show some effort, it's like you are in a hurry and just want to give your solutions, which is extremely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{j=0}^{k} {k \choose j} {m \choose k-j}=$$  Coefficient of $x^{j+k-j}=x^k$ in $$(1+x)^{n+m}= {n+m \choose k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have a committee of $n+m$ people, and $n$ are males and $m$ are females.

Now in how many ways can you choose $k$ people

$\binom {n+m}{k}$

Now another way to count this would be to consider all possible combinations of $j$ males and $k-j$ females and this can be done in

$\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n}{j} \cdot \binom {m}{k-j}$

Hence both sides are equal